# Lightning pager component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, slds

I'm looking for a pager component for lightning, at least a graphical one like all css frameworks offer : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination-pager

I did not find it anywhere, is anyone know where I can find it on github or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Lightning Design System (Salesforce's style guide) and the guidelines for displaying large amounts of data](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/layout/) (see Table Layouts)

> Use a table layout for flexibly viewing and managing large sets of data.
>
> The table can be of infinite length. Data is loaded as the user scrolls.

That is the best practice recommended. If you absolutely need to implement manual paging, you could add a `lightning:button` which will call the server and load more records into your list, but you will have to implement this behavior yourself:

```
<lightning:button label="Next" onclick="{! c.loadPage }" />
```

Comment: Thank you @citizen conn

Unfortunately the lazy loading is absolutely not efficient on salesforce1, so we reaaly need real pager to be able to use big amounts of datas, plus a big amount of datas use an important amount of memory event if it's not displayed.
It's looks like Salesforce does not provide real solution for this need, have to create it by myself.

Comment: The infinite scrolling was built with a mobile first approach, so I would investigate what is causing performance problems for you, since the native record lists on S1 are quite speedy.

Comment: yes but in an iframe (vf page) the uiwebview of IOS make it quite awfull.